# Potential HTTP Host header attack from malicious IP, what does it mean in practical terms for me? Should I be concerned?

Tags: xss, defense

I'm asking about an error I've got a few times in the past day, outside of the theoretical. I'm wondering what may be actually happening in my case.

The error comes from Sentry, on my ubuntu/nginx/uwsgi/Django via AWS Elastic Beanstalk stack:

`Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '54.149.10.254'. You may need to add u'54.149.10.254' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`
`Exception while resolving variable 'exception_type' in template 'unknown'.`

`54.149.10.254` is associated with `scan-15.shadowserver.org`. ALLOWED_HOSTS is there to prevent the HTTP host header attacks.

Should I be concerned? What is going on here in concrete terms?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know who shadowserver is? https://www.shadowserver.org/wiki/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I be concerned?

Not particularly.  You're being scanned by a [known non-malicious party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowserver) called 
Shadowserver.  They're [very open](http://blog.shadowserver.org/2014/03/28/the-scannings-will-continue-until-the-internet-improves/) about their activities and intent.

Bear in mind that on the Internet you're going to get scanned.  A lot.  By many people who are outright malicious.  While some may have legitimate concerns about 'scan vigilantes' like Shadowserver, Shadowserver is certainly more benign than a lot of other traffic you can expect to receive.

> What is going on here in concrete terms?

They are connecting to your web server and sending a request using an invalid Host: header - one that doesn't match your actual site, but actually matches their IP.  There are [a variety of ways the host header can be abused](http://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html); Shadowserver is looking for vulnerable IPs.  Given their mission statement, they're probably looking for web servers that can be tricked into sending or redirecting traffic to [the IP they used in the Host: header], which would indicate that those web servers can be abused in an amplification attack.

The fact that your server reports `Invalid HTTP_HOST header` leads me to believe it correctly rejects connections which don't contain a valid Host: header for your site.  Good job.